How to know the dollar amount that my employer pays for the group health plan?
Let's say I pay $600/month (deducted from my paycheck) for the premiums in my PPO plan. Is there a public place to check how much of the premium my employer pay (without needing to contact my employer)?

I don't think so, other than looking at the company's financial sheet for benefits costs and dividing by approximate number of employees. And frankly it's a useless number; it's not as if you could apply for that negotiated group health plan directly. All that matters to you is whether you can get better benefits at less cost elsewhere, and the answer is usually no.

Other than simple curiosity, why do you want to know? I don't know what you could do with the information. If you're considering buying a private insurance policy, what sort of rates your employer gets on a group plan is pretty much irrelevant.

If you want to know about this year, the employer will be the source of this information.
If you want to know about last year, then your employer may have had to report it on your W-2:

Reporting on the Form W-2
Employers that are subject to this requirement should report the value
of the health care coverage in Box 12 of the Form W-2PDF, with Code DD
to identify the amount. There is no reporting on the Form W-3 of the
total of these amounts for all the employer’s employees.
In general, the amount reported should include both the portion paid
by the employer and the portion paid by the employee. See the chart,
below, and the questions and answers for more information.

Review the chart on that same page to understand how the numbers are calculated.
